# How to execute a sequence of events in Angular using $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a div in my **view**, I want to execute a function on ng-click() which turns the background for the div to 'color a' for 30 seconds if there's no action taken then for 60 seconds then change to 'color b' and if no action is taken beyond 120 seconds just hide the div.(this can be done via adding/removing classes as well )

In essence I'm looking to execute a sequence of $timeouts in angular where one timeout leads into another.

Any help on that would be hugely appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: what's holding you back?

Comment: How I should approach it, should I create one $timeout of 120 seconds and nest the subsequent $timeouts in the root $timeout. I think I might have solved it myself. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach it by using a variable in the scope to hold the state, and chaining `$timeout`s to move between the states. So on the element that will be clicked:

```
<span ng-click="startChange()">Click me to start</span>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.state = 'a';
$scope.startChange = function() {
  $scope.state = 'b';
  return $timeout(angular.noop, 30 * 1000).then(function() {
    $scope.state = 'c';
    return $timeout(angular.noop, 60 * 1000);
  }).then(function() {
    $scope.state = 'd';
    return $timeout(angular.noop, 120 * 1000);
  }).then(function() {
    $scope.state = 'e'
  });
}
```

The `angular.noop` is just a function that does nothing. It's a slightly personal preference, but I find it a bit easier to see the flow of activity where the callback passed to `$timeout` does nothing, and all action on the scope are always in the `then` success callback of the promise.

In the template for the background div:

```
<div class="background-state-{{state}}">....</div>
```

and then in CSS set the colours:

```
.background-state-a {background-color: red}
.background-state-b {background-color: green}
.background-state-c {background-color: blue}
...
```

However, I'm not sure what else you have in the controller or your exact use-case. You might want to separate some logic out into a directive, as it might be mixing business logic with view logic.

Comment: That's a more structured approach with promises and definitely better than my approach. Thanks @Michal!

Comment: Any idea why the {{ state }} won't output in the div? I can see that when I log the `$scope` the .state is set to 'a'; but on the template it's just `<div "background-state-"></div>`

Comment: Yes: I made a mistake in my answer. I wrote `$state` instead of `$scope.state`. I've now edited it.

Comment: It actually works on {{ state }} as well but not when I want to output it in the `class` attr on the custom directive that I have and also it doesn't update it on the $timeout sequence. I can see it when I `console.log` that it's changing state, but it's not updating the value of state as it executes.

Comment: Just to confirm... the template should be `{{state}}`, but in the controller the code should be `$scope.state = ...` If this is the case, can you post a Plunkr of the issue?

Comment: having one of those when everything's seems to be wrong. haha http://plnkr.co/edit/dxL2TmCetE0g8nKUvIUH angular app won't initialize in plnkr.

Comment: There were a number of issues in the plunkr. Fixed at http://plnkr.co/edit/JjqIJSEHFrCL9bJfvtyK?p=preview . 1) Typo: you were using `$scoe` instead of `$scope`. 2) `$timeout` wasn't being injected into the controller. 3) You were using just `$state` in the controller, instead of `$scope.state` (as I was in my original answer) 4) The function `element.on` seems to cause issues sometimes. I've changed to `element.bind` Not sure why this is necessary, admittedly.

Comment: Works fine the only problem is it won't update the {{ state }} in the class attribute of my custom directive. I want to change it and bind it with the click event. thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51011/discussion-between-sinsync-and-michal-charemza)