# Stop execution of a sequence of events using $timeout

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125497/how-to-execute-a-sequence-of-events-in-angular-using-timeout) solution to start the sequence. But now I want to stop on a ng-click.
The click event if firing OK, I have confirmed on the console.log. I have tried

```
$timeout.cancel($scope.StartChange);
```

But with no success, classes are still changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but I have no idea if it's the best solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/xKBHdFhXy93NqtpVooXe?p=preview

```
  var savePromise = function(promiseObj) {
    //saves promise and returns it
    $scope.terminateEarly.push(promiseObj);
    return promiseObj;
  };

  $scope.startChange = function() {
    console.log('start');
    $scope.state = 'b';
    console.log($scope.state);
    return savePromise($timeout(angular.noop, 3 * 1000))
     .then(function() {
      $scope.state = 'c';
      console.log($scope.state);

      return savePromise($timeout(angular.noop, 6 * 1000))})
      .then(function() {
        $scope.state = 'd';
        console.log($scope.state);
        return savePromise($timeout(angular.noop, 12 * 1000))})
        .then(function() {
          $scope.state = 'e';
           console.log($scope.state);
    });
  };

  $scope.stopChange = function(tId) {
    console.log('stop');
    $scope.terminateEarly.forEach(function(t){
      $timeout.cancel(t);
    });
  };
```

Comment: it seems it's enough to cancel the last timeout ($timeout.cancel($scope.terminateEarly.slice(-1).pop());)...but I still haven't figured out why...