# passing ng-model as a parameter to a function with other parameter and than clearing ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my html

```
<input type="text" name="message" ng-model="senderMessage">

<button type="submit" ng-click="sendSenderMessage(1,5,senderMessage)">
  click me 
</button>
```

my js controller function

```
$scope.sendSenderMessage = function (bsid, srid, message) {
  $scope.senderMessage = message; 
  $http.post(url + 'c_chat/sendSenderMessageJson', {
    bsid: bsid,
    srid: srid,
    message: $scope.senderMessage
  })
  .success(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.chatForm();
    $scope.startChat(srid);
  });
}
```

where

```
$scope.chatForm = function () {
  $scope.senderMessage = "";
}
```

MY problem is that i can not reset $scope.senderMessage blank

Comment: Why don't you just use `$scope.senderMessage=""` in the success function ?

Comment: why you are passing message in click function.. angular provides two way binding so use $scope.senderMessage directly in function.

Comment: @Jenny because i am also passing two other argument that not need model

Comment: that's ok if you send sendSenderMessage(1,5) and use $scope.senderMessage  when you need it

Comment: @Jenny if you look at js function i have assign it to scope

Comment: but why angular provides better way to handle... you should not pass $scope values.

Answer (score 1):

you should provide .error(function(data)) to post request because if error occurs then $scope.chatForm will not called and $scope.senderMessage will remain same.

or you should do like

```
 var tempMessage = angular.copy(message);
$scope.senderMessage = ""; 
 $http.post(url + 'c_chat/sendSenderMessageJson', {
    'bsid'    : bsid ,
    'srid'    : srid ,
    'message' : tempMessage 

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.sendSenderMessage = function (bsid, srid, message) {
  $scope.senderMessage = message; 
  $http.post(url + 'c_chat/sendSenderMessageJson', {
    bsid: bsid,
    srid: srid,
    message: $scope.senderMessage
  })
  .success(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.chatForm();
    $scope.startChat(srid);
  });
  where $scope.chatForm = function() {
  $scope.senderMessage = "";
  $timeout(angular.noop); //use
 //try let me know again u are getting same problem.
 }
```

angular.noop is an empty function that can be used as a placeholder when you need to pass some function as a param.

[For more details regarding angular.noop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125497/how-to-execute-a-sequence-of-events-in-angular-using-timeout)

Comment: off-course message is successfully posted and retrieved but input field is not clered

Comment: @shabirullah What is `where` ?

Comment: @Weedoze sorry?what do you mean what is where? input field does not seem to be empty after message submitted

Comment: then use $timeout(angular.noop) @shabirullah and also inject $timeout

Comment: @shabirullah You are using `where $scope.chatForm` - what is `where` ?

Comment: @Weedoze where is not programming word i use it for description

Comment: Please do not use `.success` and .`error`, they are officially deprecated and have always been bad. Use `.then` and `.catch`.

Comment: @ankitgupta i am using 1.5.5 version?is it not a problem

Comment: @ankitgupta not yet

Comment: use  $scope.senderMessage = ""; in success method directly.check once